# Timeout issue sending information over WCF to AIF services

Tags: wcf, aif

I'm getting an error when I call my WCF service from the client it returns a message saying The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 59 seconds. Increase the timeout value passed to call to request or increase sendtimeout value on the binding.

How my application works. It passes a datatable to a wcf service. From the wcf service it passes the information to an AIF service and writes to the journal then returns.  I have increased my timeout throughout all configs.

Client for Example:

```
 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IETL" closeTimeout="01:30:00"
                openTimeout="01:30:00" receiveTimeout="01:30:00" sendTimeout="01:30:00"
                allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

WCF Web Config:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity" openTimeout="01:30:00" receiveTimeout="01:30:00" sendTimeout="01:30:00" closeTimeout="01:30:00"
      allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="1500000000" maxBufferSize="1500000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="1500000000" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="1500000000" maxStringContentLength="1500000000"
        maxArrayLength="1500000000" maxBytesPerRead="1500000000" maxNameTableCharCount="1500000000" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netTcpBinding>
           <binding name="NetTcpBinding_GeneralJournalPC_Service" />
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Also added

On top of that it then calls the AIF service from the wcf service.. I also updated all the bindings in the AIF service to increased limits.  It works on smaller files but again once it hits this limit it fails.. i don't know why as i have changed everything.

Comment: Go through https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2015/04/07/requesting-large-packages-across-ax-aif-can-result-in-timeout-errors-after-30-seconds-regardless-of-your-timeout-values/ and http://ax2012exceldataimport.blogspot.com/2012/08/dynamics-ax-2012-excel-add-in-issues.html.

Comment: Tried that, didn't seem to work ..

Comment: Get Ax Trace (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149695.aspx) and analyse the performance of customization to do improvements.

Comment: What is your execution timeout value?  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />